# Firebase Storage upload php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm currently trying to upload to the Firebase Cloud Storage using php, but running into an issue.

I have a form in html, that takes the uploaded file (in my case an image), and passes it to a php file.

This image is very small, 12.8kB, and a JPEG image.

The php file takes the image, and tries to upload it to the storage.
My current php code is roughly:

```
$storage = new StorageClient(['projectId' => '<my_project_id> ']);
$bucket = $storage->bucket('images');
$bucket->upload($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']);
```

I can get it to print the bucket name, and it's details, so I know it's not that part that is causing the error.

The error I get is,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: A name is required when data is of type string or null. 
in /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php:258 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Images/uploadImage.php(74): Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket->upload('/tmp/phpA9SAM8') 
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php on line 258
```

Oh, I am also working on 16.04 Ubuntu if that matters, with apache2.  (But I've been able to upload to my own computer with php.  Just refactoring to use Firebase now)

EDIT:
When I've changed my code to be

```
$bucket->upload(
    file_get_contents($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']),
    [
        'name' => $_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']
    ]
);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\NotFoundException: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:263
 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(168): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) 
#1 /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Upload/MultipartUploader.php(64): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#2 /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php(268): Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader->upload() 
#3 /var/www/html/Images/uploadImage.php(75): Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket->upload('/tmp/phpR2vYYg', Array) 
#4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Images/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 263
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `$_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']`, you are using the temporary name of the uploaded image as the contents, not the actual image file.

The quickes way to solve this is to use:

```
$bucket->upload(
    file_get_contents($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']),
    [
        'name' => $_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']
    ]
);
```

The `upload` method accepts an array of options (including the target file name) as described in the method's PHPDoc: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/Bucket.php#L216

Please keep in mind though that there are security implications when using the uploaded file name (not the `tmp_name`) directly, so please make sure to validate and sanitize the uploaded files before moving them to your cloud storage.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Though now encountering an error where it can't find the file apparently :/

Comment: Perhaps this article can help: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: I got it to work!  Found out I wasn't calling my bucket properly >.<

Comment: not worked for me throwing error saying `tmp/file/path/filename.ext` not found